# Can I use Excel's autofill with a custom pattern?

Tags: excel, vba, autofill

I'm trying to auto fill the following rows;

```
Row A1
Row A1
Row A2
Row A2
...
Row A12
Row A12
Row B1
Row B1
Row B2
Row B2
....
```

From A-P, 1-12

How can I quickly auto fill this? 
Currently the drag down just repeats the pattern and doesn't ascend the pattern.

Thanks in advance.

Generally in programming I would loop A-P & nest a 1-12 loop within. However, in excel I'm not so sure.

Comment: Just to clarify what your result should look like, please add a screenshot of the result pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Sub DAdwadw()

Dim i As Integer
Dim arr(0 To 16) As String
Dim count As Integer


arr(1) = "A"
arr(2) = "B"
arr(3) = "C"
arr(4) = "D"
arr(5) = "E"
arr(6) = "F"
arr(7) = "G"
arr(8) = "H"
arr(9) = "I"
arr(10) = "J"
arr(11) = "K"
arr(12) = "L"
arr(13) = "M"
arr(14) = "N"
arr(15) = "O"
arr(16) = "P"
arr(17) = "Q"
arr(18) = "R"
arr(19) = "S"
arr(20) = "T"
arr(21) = "U"
arr(22) = "V"
arr(23) = "W"
arr(24) = "X"
arr(25) = "Y"
arr(26) = "Z"

count = 1

For i = 1 To 8
    Dim letter As String

    For p = 1 To 58

        letter = arr(i) & p

        Cells(count, 1).Value = letter
        Cells(count + 1, 1).Value = letter

        count = count + 2
    Next p

Next i

End Sub
```

This is how I ended up doing it.

Comment: Not sure why you have all the letters of the alphabet. `arr(17) = "Q"` and subsequent letters would throw a "Subscript out of range" error. Unless you meant `26` instead of `16` when declaring `arr`.

Answer (score 3):

Use INDEX with some math:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$P$12,MOD(ROW(1:1)-1,12)+1,INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/12)+1)
```

[image]

---

Edit, I missunderstood:

```
=CHAR(INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/12)+65)&MOD(ROW(1:1)-1,12)+1
```

will fill the column with your pattern as you drag down.

[image]

Comment: Hey buddy, this isn't really what I'm intending to do. I'm looking to generate the data using autofill. To easily create A1,A1,A2,A2.... and so on. Opposed to entering the data manually.

Comment: The data is only to show it is grabbing the correct cell. The formula returns the value in those cells in the pattern you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not opposed to having a helper column in B that you can autofill, you can copy this down all the way starting from `A1` and then copy and special paste just the values back in. Just make sure that the autofill starts from 0 to whatever number of cells you want

`=SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,CEILING((B1+0.01)/12,1),4),"1","") & MOD(B1,12)+1`

**EDIT**

Sorry for the delay, but I found some time to rewrite it in VBA so that it no longer requires a helper column.

```
Sub Filler()
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 0 To 191
        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
            .Cells(i + 1, 1) = Split(.Cells(1, Int((i + 0.01) / 12) + 1).Address, "$")(1) & i Mod 12 + 1
        End With
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Would a macro not be the way to go?

Comment: My bad I thought you wanted to use the drag down in the sheet. I'll try to update my answer later.

Answer (score 0):

I think you were looking for something like that:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestGeneratePattern()
    GeneratePattern Rows:=12, Columns:=16
End Sub

Public Sub GeneratePattern(Rows As Long, Columns As Long)
    Dim strRow As String
    Dim strCol As String

    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = 1 To Rows * Columns
        strRow = iRow - ((iRow - 1) \ Rows) * Rows 'count rows from 1 to 12 
        strCol = Cells(1, ((iRow - 1) \ Rows) + 1).Address(True, False) 'increase column every 12 rows
        strCol = Left(strCol, InStr(1, strCol, "$") - 1) 'get column letter

        Cells(iRow * 2 - 1, "A").Resize(RowSize:=2).Value = strCol & strRow 'write value in 2 cells at once
    Next iRow
End Sub
```